# Working Syntax for Rsync Copy of a set of 2 or more Hard-linked Folder Trees while maintaining this specific archive structure?

Tags: rsync, directory-structure, cygwin, hard-link

**Working Syntax for Rsync Copy of a set of 2 or more Hard-linked Folder Trees while maintaining this specific archive structure?**

PS: Would this be a better fit in SO or SU SE?

Template of Current/ Example Folder Structure:

```
Base Folder (Source): 

C:\iMazing
   \Backups

    \{device A UDID} // Last backup of Device A (AL)
    \{device B UDID} // Last backup of Device B (BL)
    \iMazing.Versions 

       \Versions
          \{device A UDID} // Backup history of Device A (AL) 
          \{device B UDID} // Backup history of Device B (BH)
```

```
Base Folder (Destination): 

S:\ExtHDD\APPLE\iMazing.Backups  

    \{device A UDID} // Last backup of Device A (AL)
    \{device B UDID} // Last backup of Device B (BL)
    \iMazing.Versions 

       \Versions
          \{device A UDID} // Backup history of Device A (AH) 
          \{device B UDID} // Backup history of Device B (BH)
```

> Folder Trees under Folders with UDID Names

- AL : {device A UDID} // Last backup of Device A
- AH : {device A UDID} // Backup history of Device A
- **AL & AH Form a SINGLE 2 SET with Hard Links in between.**
- **We'd like to work INDIVIDUAL SET at a time**

How to use Rsync (preferable via Cygwin RSync or one of mentioned Windows variations) to :

- Copy a **Hard Linked INDIVIDUAL SET e.g. {AL + AH}** from C drive to S drive while

  - Preserving Hard Links
  - Maintain the Sub-tree folder structure
- Without causing issues on Windows or its NTFS Folder & File structure

Also:

- Can we do only an INDIVIDUAL SET at a time (one single RSync command) or multiple SPECIFIED SETs?
- Typically we have 2 SETs, how would commandline for Rsync change if it was a 3 SET (SET with 3 HL folders) within a structure

A Real/ Actual Example with UDID Folder name:

- **XL & XH which are Hard Linked folder trees, together make up a SET**.

```
Base Folder (Source): 
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\iMazing\Backups

  \f22ebcffcdd1b508d3f7564431a9db98d69208ef-20190414-170122 //..(XL)  
  \iMazing.Versions
   \Versions  
    \f22ebcffcdd1b508d3f7564431a9db98d69208ef-20190414-170122 //..(XH)
```

---

**Reference list of Tools for Hard Link preserving Copying:**
https://superuser.com/questions/997190/copy-to-another-ntfs-disk-and-preserve-hard-links/

- **Rsync** variations under Windows

  - (Several *Nix & Windows: Cygwin variations, CW RSync, Delta Copy/ Syncrify/ Synaman, GRsync, RsyncBackup, Rsync.exe pkg, Rclone, AcroSync, YInterSync)
- **ln.exe - command line hardlinks** - http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html (Win)

---

Comment: Not sure why this should be a problem. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes. Single folder trees, Yes & abstract Syntax with HL, Yes (https://superuser.com/a/1001102/183467). But not sure how to do HLinked sets of Folder Trees and maintain that structure. The linked syntax is vague and I cant find a good example to do whats asked & maintain structure. I'm not an Rsync expert and not too many such examples around

Comment: And add to it NTFS/ Windows/ Cygwin issues and from my reading there's more arguments for that. Would just linking all my reading/ pages/ articles & SE QnAs help you realize I've been looking & trying

Answer (score 1):

I've found it rather difficult to understand your earlier iterations of this question, so I'm going to restate a simplified version of what I think you mean, along with a corresponding worked example:

**Structure**

```
C:\iMazing\Backups\
    AL\
        files...
    BL\
        files...
    iMazing.Versions\Versions\
        AH\
            files...
        BH\

S:\ExtHDD\APPLE\iMazing.Backups\
    AL\
        destination files...
    BL\
        destination files...
    iMazing.Versions\Versions\
        AH\
            destination files...
        BH\
            destination files...
```

Requirement is to copy `AL\...` and `AH\...` from `C:` to `S:` while maintaining hard links and relative structure.

**Worked example**

```
mkdir -p iMazing/Backups/{AL,BL,iMazing.Versions/Versions/{AH,BH}} ExtHDD/APPLE/iMazing.Backups
touch iMazing/Backups/{AL/albackup,BL/blbackup}
touch iMazing/Backups/iMazing.Versions/Versions/{AH/ahbackup,BH/bhbackup}
```

At this point you can `ls -R` or `find` to see what I've done. There should be files `albackup`, `ahbackup`, `blbackup` and `bhbackup` in the `AL`, `AH`, `BL`, and `BH` directories. We're going to copy the `AL` and `AH` directories to the target:

```
rsync --dry-run -avHPR iMazing/Backups/./AL iMazing/Backups/./iMazing.Versions/Versions/AH ExtHDD/APPLE/iMazing.Backups/
```

The `-R` (`--relative`) flag retains the source path(s) from the `/./` marker. In the example this means that `iMazing/Backups/` is stripped, and the remainder appended to the destination path.

Once the `--dry-run` (`-n`) is removed this will copy files and directories from the source AL and AH directories to the target, maintaining internal hard links and structure.

**Question solution**

Since this is Cygwin you need to use forward slashes and paths starting with `/cygdrive/{DriveLetter}`. To maintain links you need to include the `-H` flag (`--hard-links`).

```
rsync -aHR /cygdrive/C/iMazing/Backups/./AL /cygdrive/C/iMazing/Backups/./iMazing.Versions/Versions/AH /cygdrive/ExtHDD/APPLE/iMazing.Backups/
```

You can include the `-v` (`--verbose`) and/or `-P` (`--partial --progress`) flags if you want to see what's going on. In this situation `rsync` will not bother with its infamous "delta" algorithm or compression (these only work when there are two servers involved in an `rsync` client-server configuration across a network). If you could run an instance of `rsync` on the server hosting your S: drive that could be far more efficient.

Add `--dry-run` to see what would happen without it actually doing anything.

Comment: You’re missing a key part I don’t want entire base folder, only the SETs under & in their structure. Wouldn’t have to post this question with so much detail otherwise

Comment: @AlexS this command won't copy the base folder path. Please try it.

Comment: @roima - Have you first understood what is COMPOSED of a SET? Please see the BlockQuoted (in Yellow) part above of what is a SET {AL - AH}. How would you copy an INDIVIDUAL SET {AL - AH} without referring to it? We do not want to copy ALL the SETS at one time. But choose which SET {AL - AH} or {BL - BH} at a given time and copy it WITH ITS STRUCTURE INTACT.

Comment: @roima - I've updated the question with more metadata / info as well as specified in comments what is a SET.

Comment: @AlexS try that. I _think_ I now understand what you're asking.

Comment: I've been reading a bunch about _rsync_ and came across --_include_, --exclude, .._from_ / _filter_ etc type of parameters . Do you think they could be better leveraged for such an operation?

Comment: @AlexS, I don't think they would add value here. Given my understanding of your requirements I stand by my solution. (If I'd needed to use `include`/`exclude`/`filter` I would have done so, and explained their use.)

Comment: Maybe not needed; but another way of doing that same. Could you possibly share? How to do same using these 3?

Comment: @AlexS but I wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: So....did this work?