# How is it possible to call CwRsync.exe via a Bash Script with variables and arguments?

Tags: command, executable, arguments, cygwin, parameter

This is the commandline currently used to call Rsync that's part of Cygwin 64 install.

```
rsync -aqHPR $CygSrcRoot/./$FolA1 $CygSrcRoot/./iMazing.Versions/Versions/$FolA1 $CygDstRoot/$DstCountFol --progress --log-file=$CygDstRoot/$DstCountFol"_Log.txt"
```

It utilizes the Relative path insights obtained from this QnA:

[Working Syntax for Rsync Copy of a set of 2 or more Hard-linked Folder Trees while maintaining this specific archive structure?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541231/working-syntax-for-rsync-copy-of-a-set-of-2-or-more-hard-linked-folder-trees-whi)

While using the "concatenated path building" using a Bash/ Shell script (if required can update and post details it):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040165/clean-way-to-build-concatenated-multiple-source-paths-and-convert-for-cygwin-rsy

I'd like to execute this `.SH script` (I'm guessing likely under Bash), but I'd like to have it "**call, use and execute**" the **Rsync.exe from CwRsync**.

I have also made a **duplicate copy** of it in same bin folder & **renamed it** `cwrsync.exe` just to ***avoid a name collision*** under the Shell window.

---

PS: Do note, I am using ConEmu on Windows to run CMD & Cygwin windows for better usage.

Comment: I'm sorry, but yet again your question makes no sense to me whatsoever. Are you asking how to use a particular `rsync` instead of one that's in your `$PATH`? If so, why not use the absolute path to the executable? If that's not what you're asking please **provide an example** of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh, and if your last `rsync` question got an answer that helped you, please would you accept the answer.